# Command fails in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, script, openssl

I'm trying to script the OpenSSL `ec` command. The script is used to validate a collection of keys produced by another library. The script is shown below after the question.

The following works from a terminal:

```
openssl ec -in ec-enc-priv-xxx.pem -passin pass:test -text -noout
```

The following works from a terminal:

```
openssl ec -in ec-enc-priv-xxx.pem -passin pass:test -text -noout >/dev/null
```

However, when I script the last one, I get prompted for a password:

```
$ ./pem-verify.sh 
read RSA key
read RSA key
read RSA key
read DSA key
read DSA key
read DSA key
read EC key
read EC key
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

The same code works for RSA and DSA keys in the script. The issue is with the encrypted EC private key only.

Any ideas how to work around this?

---

```
#! /bin/sh

# Script to verify the test keys written by pem-test.cpp

#################
# RSA keys

# The RSA command returns 0 on success

openssl rsa -in rsa-pub-xxx.pem -pubin -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read RSA public key"
fi

openssl rsa -in rsa-priv-xxx.pem -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read RSA private key"
fi

openssl rsa -in rsa-enc-priv-xxx.pem -passin pass:test -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read encrypted RSA private key"
fi

#################
# DSA keys

# The DSA command is broken. It returns 1 when using '-noout' option
#  instead of 0. A patch was submitted to RT.

openssl dsa -in dsa-pub-xxx.pem -pubin -text -noout >/dev/null

openssl dsa -in dsa-priv-xxx.pem -text -noout >/dev/null

openssl dsa -in dsa-enc-priv-xxx.pem -passin pass:test -text -noout >/dev/null

#################
# EC keys

# The EC command returns 0 on success

openssl ec -in ec-pub-xxx.pem -pubin -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read EC public key"
fi

openssl ec -in ec-priv-xxx.pem -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read EC private key"
fi

openssl ec -in ec-enc-priv-xxx.pem -passin pass:test -text -noout >/dev/null
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Failed to read encrypted EC private key"
fi
```

Comment: Did you try to set a temp variable, use `env:var` instead of `pass:password`, and to delete the variable just after?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue can  no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I despise these kinds of answers, but I cannot duplicate the problem since rebooting the MacBook Pro. So the answer in this instance appear to be reboot. Sigh...

Moving to close the question because the issue is not reproducable.